# Why is SIGUSR1 signal caught by epoll_wait instead of sigwait even though SIGUSR1 is blocked

Tags: linux, signals, epoll

I have a C++ program with a number of threads.  At the start of the main thread (before any threads are spawned) I block SIGUSR1 using sigprocmask.  I then create two threads, one waits for a SIGUSR1 using sigwait and the other monitors file descriptors using epoll_wait.  For some reason when I send a SIGUSR1 to this program it is caught by the epoll_wait and not by the sigwait.

Linux Version 4.9.165

I have tried explicitly blocking the SIGUSR1 before calling epoll_wait but that does not solve the problem.  I have also tried using epoll_pwait directly.

```
// main thread

   // ...

   sigset_t sigset;
   sigemptyset(&sigset);
   sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &sigset, NULL);

   // ...


//thread 1

   // ...

   sigset_t sigset;
   int sig;
   sigemptyset(&sigset);
   sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
   auto ret  = sigwait(&sigset, &sig);

   if (ret != 0)
   {
        std::cout << "sigwait failed\n";
   }

   // ...

//thread 2

    static constexpr int MAX_EVENTS = 10;
    struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];
    int timeout = -1;

    // ...

    sigset_t oldset;
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, &oldset);
    std::cout << (sigismember(&oldset, SIGUSR1) ? "SIGUSR1 blocked " : "SIGUSR1 not blocked ") << "in epoll thread\n";

    epoll_wait(epollFd.Get(), static_cast<struct epoll_event*>(events), MAX_EVENTS, timeout);

    if (nfds < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Epoll wait failed: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
    }


    // ...
```

This gives me the output "Epoll wait failed: Interrupted system call" an the sigwait thread never wakes up.

I also see the "SIGUSR1 blocked in epoll thread" indicating that before the epoll_wait the SIGUSR1 signal was blocked.

My understanding is that child threads should inherit the signal masks of their parents, that the epoll_wait should be treated as an epoll_pwait with a null sigmask (and thus not alter the signal mask), and that the signal should go to the only thread that has the signal unblocked (being the one with sigwait).  Am I incorrect?

Comment: You might want to read the docs for `sigprocmask`, particularly this part: "*The use of sigprocmask() is unspecified in a multithreaded process; see pthread_sigmask(3).*".

Comment: The program was actually using pthread_sigmask, I just goofed when writing up the question, my apologies, I have corrected my post.  I am going to try moving the sigwait to the main thread as one of my colleagues has indicated that that may help.